# Метод перед конструктором?

Tags: python

У меня не работает метод  - если страна США, то цена больше на 50 процентов. Мой код должен оставаться конструктором

```
class Person:
name = "ivan"
age = 10

def __init__(self, country, price, study):
    self.country=country
    self.price=price
    self.study=study
def _self(self, country, price, study):
    self.country=country
    self.price=price
    self.study=study

def countryPrice(self):#створення метода  залежності ціни від країни
    if self.country == "USA":
        self.price += self.price * 0.5


class Student(Person):
    course=1

vlad=Person("USA", 22, "VTC")
print(vlad.country+ " "+str(vlad.price)+" "+str(vlad.study))
```

Comment: Код в вопросе сломан. Пожалуйста, исправьте отступы как должно быть.

Comment: исправил что не так

Comment: @vitalieognatov то что у тела класса должен быть отступ. У класса Person в вашем коде отступа нет. Такой код не запустится вообще.

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую перечитать раздел о классах и их функциях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод, конечно же, работает. Просто чтобы увидеть это, нужно этот метод вызвать, а не просто написать в код и думать, что оно само вдруг выполнится.

Если нужно в конструктор, то никто не мешает добавить это условие в конструктор:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, country, price, study):
        self.country=country
        self.price=price
        if self.country == "USA":
            self.price += self.price * 0.5
        self.study=study

    def _self(self, country, price, study):
        self.country=country
        self.price=price
        self.study=study

    def country_price(self):#створення метода  залежності ціни від країни
        if self.country == "USA":
            self.price += self.price * 0.5

vlad=Person("USA", 22, "VTC")
print(vlad.country + " " + str(vlad.price) + " " + vlad.study)
```

Вывод:

> USA 33.0 VTC

Если нужно вызывать отдельной функцией, то это делается так:

```
vlad.country_price()
```

Тогда нужно из конструктора убрать это условие.

Comment: оно так не работает) вы вообще проверяли или киньте код полностью пожалуйста. И мне нужно не условия а метод!

Comment: Работает, почему бы этому не работать. Добавил код.

Comment: условия может быть методом?

Comment: Какой вам нужен метод? Вы там написали, что должно оставаться конструктором. Я дополнил ваш конструтор.

Comment: Вижу спасибо, помогли очень